# C function: take string as parameter and print it

Tags: c, printf

In the process of learning C... trying to create a function for some test cases; I want something that prints out the name of each test case taken from input.  Just wanted to eliminate some dup code in each test case which is `printf("Testing foo); etc. Have a function which would be called like this: outTesting("foo"); Pretty basic, but I'm unfamiliar with some of these data structures; help is appreciated.  Here's what I have so far:

```
void outTesting(const char *c) {
    printf("\n\nTesting %u\n_____________\n\n", (char) *c);
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%s`:

```
printf("\n\nTesting %s\n_____________\n\n", c);
```

Answer (score 2):

That should probably be:

```
printf("\n\nTesting %s\n_____________\n\n", c);
```

instead?